# Having trouble with paths returned by flowPath in raster R-package

Tags: r, r-raster

Paths returned by the flowPath function in the raster package consist of segments parallel to the x- and y-axes.

Starting with the *Vector Field Plots* example in the rasterVis documentation (https://oscarperpinan.github.io/rastervis/), I try to find the flow-path from a starting point on the surface, but the path output is incorrect.

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
proj <- CRS('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84')
df <- expand.grid(x = seq(-2, 2, .01), y = seq(-2, 2, .01))
df$z <- with(df, (3*x^2 + y)*exp(-x^2-y^2))
r <- rasterFromXYZ(df, crs=proj)

# Up to this point we follow the example in the rasterVis documentation
# Now attempt to find the path from a point on the surface

contour(r$z)
r.fd<-terrain(r,opt='flowdir')
r.c<-cellFromXY(r,cbind(-1,0))
r.p<-flowPath(r.fd,r.c)
p.xy<-xyFromCell(r.fd,r.p)
lines(p.xy,col='green')
```

[Flow path from point (-1,0) depicting undesired behavior.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idrlo.png)

As you can see above, the flow path proceeds to the minimum at approximately (0,-.8) by moving towards +x and then -y.  I have been unable to construct a data set which does not exhibit this problem.  However:  the example included in the *flowPath* documentation (in the *raster* package, using the *volcano* data) produces output one might expect and does not exhibit this problem.

What am I doing incorrectly that I cannot extend the example in the rasterVis documentation?

Addendum:  My reason for questioning the output may be more a misunderstanding of what *flowPath* is supposed to return. I expected the kind of path a droplet might follow as it moves downhill.  Like this:

[Expected flowPath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayLZB.png)

This was computed using a simple steepest-descent walk.  However, if (as stated by respondent Hijmans) flowPath is working as intended, then I may need to find another function which provides the path droplets would follow moving downhill.

Answer (score 0):

Why is the path incorrect? It looks good to me. Illustrated by aggregating and labeling.

```
library(raster)
proj <- CRS('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84')
df <- expand.grid(x = seq(-2, 2, .01), y = seq(-2, 2, .01))
df$z <- with(df, (3*x^2 + y)*exp(-x^2-y^2))
r <- rasterFromXYZ(df, crs=proj)
r <- aggregate(r, 25) * 10

r.fd <- terrain(r, opt='flowdir')
r.p <- flowPath(r.fd, cbind(-1,0))
p.xy <- xyFromCell(r.fd,r.p)

plot(r)
lines(p.xy,col='green', lwd=2)
text(r)
```

Add some noise to get a more wiggly path

```
set.seed(01234)
r <- rasterFromXYZ(df, crs=proj)
r <- aggregate(r, 10) * 10
r <- r + runif(ncell(r), 1, 2)
r.fd <- terrain(r, opt='flowdir')
r.p <- flowPath(r.fd, cbind(-1,0))
p.xy <- xyFromCell(r.fd,r.p)

plot(r)
lines(p.xy,col='green', lwd=2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply,  I expected a path that would follow the streamlines in the vector plot output in the rasterVis documentation (q.v.)  In this case, I expected a flowPath more like the one I add to my question above.